# website with jazz guitar chords and photos of hands?

Tags: guitar, learning, chords, jazz

I'm getting so frustrated with the terrible signal to noise ratio searching for guitar chord websites so thought I'd ask here. I'm looking for something with:

- lots of different voicings for chords, including jazz voicings
- well organized/searchable
- real photos of hands playing them

tips appreciated! thanks!

Comment: What problems are you having? There are a large number of chord sites I have seen, and they are all perfectly serviceable, offering inversions, search functions etc.

Comment: I think your requirement for photos of hands is the sticking point. Very quickly, one learns to translate a chord diagram into fingering, so I don't think anyone is likely to put in the effort to photograph hundreds of chords. It's difficult to see what's going on under the fingers anyway. Diagrams are better.

Answer (score 4):

Try http://www.jazzguitarlessons.net

It might not have everything you want, but I took personnal lessons with this guy and I can tell you that everything was always related to his website. This is a fountain of jazz knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

[Chord-C.com](http://chord-c.com) worked for me in the past, I haven't used it in a while but it was very nice when I did. CHORD-C shows pictures of chords, and you can search chords by putting in the fingerings and it will show you that chord / different voicings.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.justinguitar.com/en/JA-000-Jazz.php is a great one. Justin is a great teacher. Not only he teaches the chords, he explains the theory behind them, and gives examples on how to use the chords and voice leading. The entire website is a great resource for guitarists in general, not just jazz.